# How to import data into Supabase table

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

first of all, I am sorry this question may look stupid but I am a complete beginner in this field.

I am currently building a web app using no code tool and I want to use supabase for the database back-end.

I am willing to imports contacts from Meta forms and also a custom form I have on my website to populate one of my table in supabase.

I am wondering if its something technically possible with supabase ? In which way ?

No problem not to give all the technical details but if I could get some clues would be nice.

Thanks a lot.